How do I force Grafana Alloy to generate local log files on Windows?
According to the Alloy documentation, when Alloy is running as a Windows service all logs are written to the event viewer. I can see those logs without any problem. While useful for incidental debugging, this has the downside requiring a lot of extra steps to get a log dump for support tickets or when opening github issues and the like. The Windows Event Viewer is also just not a great UI for looking through lots of logging in general, and Alloy is pretty verbose.
The logging block does have a write_to argument that points to a list(LogsReceiver). Is there a Loki or other component that can write to a local file? Alternatively, is there a way to redirect stderr to a local file for just the alloy service?
